# How to demonstrate a play application remotely

Tags: playframework-2.0

I have created an application using the play framework for a college assignment. I created it on my home computer, but need to demonstrate it next week in college from a lab machine. These machines don't have play installed on them and I can't install anything on them. I'm not able to afford at the moment to get the application hosted online, so is there a way for me to avoid lugging my desktop into college.

Note: Somebody suggested using [Heroku](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ProductionHeroku) but having read that guide I'm left clueless as to what it is, and how I access it from the college computer. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "I can't install anything on them" - so how are people going to demonstrate any of their assignments?  You need to clarify this with your instructor instead of asking on SO...

Comment: Sign up for a free amazon aws account, and use one of the free tier amazon micro instances to setup your application.  I've done this quite a few times for small demos, works just fine.  You'll just need to download java and scala and install them on the cloud instance you're working with.

Answer (score 1):

Heroku is a good cloud application hosting platform and you can easily deploy your play application in a matter of 1-2 hours or even less. Only catch is you need to have a credit card to create an account with them. You wont be charged anything and since yours is a simple college project, you can get by their free package

To get started

1. Download Heroku tool belt from their site and install it on your home computer
2. create an account on heroku and note the username/password
3. using Git bash, connect to heroku, create a new app, create a local git, copy your play app to this git and push it to the remote heroku server'
   Instructions : http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ProductionHeroku
4. your application must be up and running

You can ask here if you are stuck anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just run it in development mode (or production actually) on your local machine. Then just forward the internal port to an external port, and access it via your IP. You will have to hope your machine doesn't go down, or your ISP resets your public IP address (unless you have a static IP from them).

Comment: I have no idea how to do this. Where do I even start?

Comment: This website has tutorials for most routers: http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/

You basically want to expose the port Play is running on to the outside world. I.e. you want to be able to access your public IP (you can find this out by typing "my ip" into Google) with a port, and it should have your Play app running on it. I.e. 123.456.789.101:9000 should have the Play app.

Comment: It's really not. Forwarding ports is simple.